# Unable to connect to socket using SSL and python.

Tags: python, ssl, encryption, pem

## My code

I've gone over it and had a friend of mine look at it. At this point we're both stumped and would appreciate some help.

```
import os  
import socket  
import ssl

HSM = raw_input('Please enter the IP address of the machine you are connecting to.')

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sslSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, 
    keyfile="AKMClientPrivateKey.pem", 
    certfile="AKMClientSignedCert.pem", 
    ca_certs="TCASelfSignedCert.pem", 
    cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
sslSocket.connect(('192.168.160.128', 6000))
print "Connection is successful!"
```

## The error I keep getting

I have all of the keys and certs I'm referencing in the same folder as my python file.
I've double checked the IP address and port.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect.py", line 12, in <module>
    sslSocket.connect(['192.168.160.128', 6000])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 333, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 314, in _real_connect
    self.ca_certs, self.ciphers)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 336265218] _ssl.c:351: error:140B0002:SSL
```

routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Either this was a bug that has since been fixed, or there there is a problem with your keys. But I cannot tell without knowing how the keys were generated. Please specify.